# jquery sortable + non selected li elements moving

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

This is the way the ul/li structure looks:

[image]

When I move items around this structure remains in place for FF & Chrome but in IE I get the following:

[image]

Basically the moving item seems to push the items below down.

This is the HTML structure:

```
<ul id="photoPreviews>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
```

And this is the CSS:

```
ul#photoPreviews {
    position: absolute;
    top: 350px;
    left: 39px;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 310px;
    height: 170px;
}

ul#photoPreviews li {
    float: left;
    display: inline;
}
```

How can I prevent the IE structure changing when I sort li's? 
Note: I'm using IE9.

thankyou.

Comment: How do you move them? Some sort of script? The script is probably the one making FF/Chrome "snap" in place and break in IE. Start there.

Comment: That's pretty weird... could you put up a simplified jsfiddle that shows this happening?